# Kill Script using die() but still show footer (require)

Tags: php

I have require statements for my header and footer:

```
<?php
    require "assets/php/header.php";

    // Script goes here.

    require "assets/php/footer.php";
?>
```

If I have a script in between the two statements, how can I have a die() statement in the script to end the current script, but still show the footer? If there is no way of doing this, is there any alternatives? I personally think that the require statements are obsolete, and I would love to know of some alternatives, or just a better way of setting it up. Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, you can't die and expect the script to carry on. Sounds like a simple condition statement given the current information.

Comment: Don't `die();`, throw/catch exceptions. This doesn't help you out with the current problem, it just bears mentioning. With that said, instead of dying return a useful error from the function and continue executing the script.

Comment: don't use `die`, throw an exception that is handled by a registered exception handler, and separate out the view-related code (the code that actually generates markup) There's a lot of decent MVC frameworks. Look into one of them, to see how they handle this type of thing

Comment: While exceptions can be used in this case, they really shouldn't be used for flow control.

Answer (score 0):

You should use exception.

Try something like this :

```
<?php
    try {
        require "assets/php/header.php";

        // Script goes here.

        // replace "die();" with :
        throw new Exception("I want to die");

        // folowing code executed if no exception is thrown
        require "assets/php/footer.php";
        // end of "normal" case
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        // an exception makes footer and then dies
        require "assets/php/footer.php";
        die();
    }
?>
```

you can also use this catch if you use Exception that mustn't trigger footer :

```
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        if($e->getMessage() == "I want to die") {
            // an exception asks to make footer and then dies
            require "assets/php/footer.php";
            die();
        } else {
            throw $e;
        }
    }
```

Or if you want to make it clean, make a new exception class (for instance `DieWithFooterException`) and use it like this :

```
<?php
    try {
        require "assets/php/header.php";

        // Script goes here.

        // replace "die();" with :
        throw new DieWithFooterException();

        // folowing code executed if no exception is thrown
        require "assets/php/footer.php";
        // end of "normal" case
    } catch (DieWithFooterException $dwfe) {
        // an exception asks to make footer and then dies
        require "assets/php/footer.php";
        die();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        // stuff to do with other excpetions
    }
?>
```

This said, the last solution is the nicer way to do it :)